# Sum of values in json file with certain parameters in python

Tags: python, json, linux, json-normalize

I have this python script that read the json file, pickout the car with the most ' sales' ( that part is done) but now i need to figure out how to find the year (car_year) with the most sales in our json file example in 2002, 296 cars were sold unlike 2007 arround 264 cars were sold , i figured out how to sum all of the "car_sales" of the json file but i need to find the year with the highest sales

Python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
data = json.load(open('/home/ahmed/events.json'))
#finding the item with the highest sale 
event=max(data, key=lambda ev: ev['total_sales'])
print (event)
#sum the "car_sales" of all the items in the json file
count = sum(map(lambda x: int(x['total_sales']),data))
print (count)
```

and here is the json file ( a test )

```
[
     {
        "id": 47,
        "car": {
                "car_make": "Lamborghini",
                "car_model": "Murciélago",
                "car_year": 2002
        },
        "price": "$13724.05",
        "total_sales": 149
},
{
        "id": 48,
        "car": {
                "car_make": "volvo",
                "car_model": "x20",
                "car_year": 2010
        },
        "price": "$13724.05",
        "total_sales": 10
},
{
        "id": 49,
        "car": {
                "car_make": "kia",
                "car_model": "kia1.2",
                "car_year": 2007
        },
        "price": "$13724.05",
        "total_sales": 114
},
{
        "id": 50,
        "car": {
                "car_make": "renault",
                "car_model": "p300",
                "car_year": 2002
        },
        "price": "$13724.05",
        "total_sales": 147
},
{
        "id": 51,
        "car": {
                "car_make": "ferrari",
                "car_model": "red",
                "car_year": 2007
        },
        "price": "$13724.05",
        "total_sales": 150
}
        ]
```

Answer (score 2):

- Using `pandas`

  - Use [`pandas.DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) to get sums of one of more columns
  - Use [Pandas: Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for vectorized data selection.
- Breakdown of `df['car.car_year'][df.total_sales == df.total_sales.max()]`

  - `df['car.car_year']` selects the desired column returned

    - Use `df` for all the columns
  - `[df.total_sales == df.total_sales.max()]` creates a Boolean of all rows where `total_sales` is the same as `total_sales.max()`
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by specific columns and aggregate different calculations, such as `.sum` and `.max`

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

# read the file
data = json.load(open('/home/ahmed/events.json'))

# load into pandas
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

# display(df)
   id      price  total_sales car.car_make car.car_model  car.car_year
0  47  $13724.05          149  Lamborghini    Murciélago          2002
1  48  $13724.05           10        volvo           x20          2010
2  49  $13724.05          114          kia        kia1.2          2007
3  50  $13724.05          147      renault          p300          2002
4  51  $13724.05          150      ferrari           red          2007

# sum of total_sales
df.total_sales.sum()

[out]: 
570

# year of max total_sales
df['car.car_year'][df.total_sales == df.total_sales.max()]

[out]:
4    2007
Name: car.car_year, dtype: int64

# find the total sales per year
dfg = df.groupby('car.car_year', as_index=False).agg({'total_sales': sum})

# display(dfg)
   car.car_year  total_sales
0          2002          296
1          2007          264
2          2010           10

# get the year of max sales
df.groupby('car.car_year', as_index=False)['total_sales'].sum().max()

[out]:
car.car_year    2010
total_sales      296
dtype: int64
```